Can I dual boot Ubuntu alongside Windows on a Dell Vostro 15 3510 laptop? Will their driver support Ubuntu?
Specs:
   OS: Windows 11 Home
   Version:   10.0.26100 Build 26100
   System Name:   DESKTOP-K12HMJD
   Manufacturer:  Dell
   Model: Vostro 15 3510
   Architecture: x64-based PC
   CPU: 11th Gen Intel Core i5-1135G7 @ 2.40GHz, 2419 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)
   BIOS Mode: UEFI
   RAM: 8.00 GB

This question is similar to: Will my device work with Ubuntu?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I installed on Dell 5310, but had charging issue & had to return to Dell. Both Windows & Ubuntu worked when returned. Same issue returned again & only Ubuntu worked. Could not fix Windows with any of many suggestions, and only fix was total restore of Dell image, which then erased Ubuntu. I then installed Ubuntu on external SSD and it works just as well as internal & can then be used with other systems.
